# geotiff image transformed from rst using gdal_transform is shifted

Tags: gdal, geotiff

i've been trying to convert a geotiff image to .rst and again back to geotiff (i need both ways and figured i could check wether the Output is equal to the original).
Problem is: the output Image is shifted and i really have no clue what im doing wrong.

here is what i do:

> gdal_translate -of rst -a_srs EPSG:32632 Input.tif Output.rst
>
> gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs EPSG:32632 Output.rst Output.tif

now the Output.tif is shifted upward by the size of the Image. My assumption is that somehow coordinates are being mixed up and the top left corner of the Input Image is used as the bottom left corner for the Output.

Does somebody have a clue how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please run `gdalinfo` on all of the input and out files? What does the metadata look like? This will test your assumption as to whether to top left corner is being used as the bottom left corner.

Comment: original geotiff: ul (0,0), ll (0,746), ur (683,0), lr (683,746) . 
transformed Image: ul (0,746), ll (0,0), ur (683,746), lr (683,0)

Answer (score 0):

Try being explicit about what the output corner coordinates should be. To assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file add the `-a_ullr` option and provide corner coordinates in the form of `ulx uly lrx lry`. GDAL usually will generate these implicitly from the metadata of the input file, but I've noticed that prescribing them myself sometimes eliminates these issues.

For example:

`gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs EPSG:32632 -a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry Output.rst Output.tif`